# How can a JavaScript object property be set to be a function, for example FileReader.onload?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm learning JS and have gotten stumped by the code example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload).

```
// Callback from a <input type="file" onchange="onChange(event)">
function onChange(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    // The file's text will be printed here
    console.log(e.target.result)
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

My understanding is a property of an object is a value, for example

```
var car = {brand: "Honda"}
```

So what does the code below mean?

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    // The file's text will be printed here
    console.log(e.target.result)
  };
```

I've read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload)

> The FileReader.onload property contains an event handler executed when the load event is fired,

but that does not make sense to me.

Comment: It means the value of object property can be a function as well. It can be anything basically, a simple string, number, a function, another object, etc...

Comment: You should take a look at [the documentation for defining methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_methods)

Comment: because function is an object - easier explanation from the first google search: https://codeburst.io/javascript-functions-understanding-the-basics-207dbf42ed99

Comment: It means that a function is a value as well. Just like you can store them in variables, you can assign them to object properties.

Comment: Just like HTMLElement.onclick or many other EventTargets, this interface exposes an onevent IDL attribute which will get called when a particular event will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property of an object can also be a function that can be invoked with dot notation. In your example,

```
reader.onload(paramsData)
```

would call the function with paramsData as the argument.

I suggest you study Crockford's books or lectures on JavaScript. Here is one example:
Act III: Function the Ultimate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM